# Incompatible types: 'Dynamic array' and 'array of string' in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have a class like this:

```
Programmer = Class(Worker)
private
  // Some code here
  programmingLanguages: array of String;
  numOfProgrammingLanguages: integer;
public
  // Some code here
  procedure SetProgrammingLanguages(newLanguages: array of String);
  function GetNumOfProgrammingLanguages(languages: array of string) : integer;
end;
```

When I write the following code for the `SetProgrammingLanguages` method, I get an error:

```
procedure Programmer.SetProgrammingLanguages(newLanguages: array of String);
begin
  programmingLanguages := newLanguages;
end;
```

> Incompatible types: 'Dynamic array' and 'array of string'

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please read my [article about open array parameters](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html). It might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to first declare a new type, say `TProgrammingLanguages = array of string;`. Then use that in both the class declaration and in the method parameter.

The method parameter as you have it written now is an `open array parameter` which is different from the dynamic array type you use for the `programminglanguages` field.

To learn about `Open array parameters` see the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: Tnx, It works for me.

Comment: That is a risky solution. You will now have two references to the same object. The asker might prefer copy semantics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you propose better solution?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. You might want to take another reference, in the knowledge that assigning to `programmingLanguages[i]` will modify the object that the caller has a reference to. Or you might want to take a copy. You might prefer to use an open array because it offers more flexibility in what you can pass. If you do that, then you should declare the arg as `const` to avoid making an unnecessary copy. We can tell you why the compiler reports that error, but I honestly don't feel we can advise you on what your code should be. Not without details of what the problem is.